# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "apikey" using 2 possible authenticators in SendGrid

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid

I got the following error when trying to send an Email via SendGrid SMTP.

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "apikey" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned the Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response.
```

[image]

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=mysecretkey
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="RPLS"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@rtsss.com
```

Comment: Input the API username encoded in `Base64`. Everyone’s `username` is `apikey`, which is `YXBpa2V5` in `Base64`. Go to the link https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html#-Sending-a-test-SMTP-email-with-Telnet and  it help you

Comment: Sendgrid might require you to whitelist the IP from where you are sending this mail.

Answer (score 1):

check your IP to be whitelisted in Sendgrid dashboard
https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/access